# Kali Linux: "Failed to fetch alsa-ucm-conf package" error

Tags: apt, kali-linux

I am updating my OS with the following command:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
```

And this is the error I get:

```
E: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/a/alsa-ucm-conf/alsa-ucm-conf_1.2.6.3-1_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: ....]

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

This is my Kali version:

```
Distributor ID: Kali
Description:    Kali GNU/Linux Rolling
Release:        2021.4
Codename:       kali-rolling
```

This is where I got the image (64bits VMWare): https://www.kali.org/get-kali/#kali-virtual-machines

EDIT: please, when you down vote explain your reasoning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When visiting http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/a/alsa-ucm-conf/ you will find that the version you are trying to have installed is not available in the repository at present.

To simply move on from this mismatch you can manually install the package. This [page](https://debian.pkgs.org/sid/debian-main-amd64/alsa-ucm-conf_1.2.6.3-1_all.deb.html) provides a link to a binary you can install by downloading and running `sudo apt install path/to/alsa-ucm-conf_1.2.6.3-1_all.deb` and then continue your Kali update routine.

Comment: Many thanks, that solved the issue